# JQuery/CSS Calendar

Tags: php, jquery, json, unix-timestamp

I am looking to implement the following:
[**Calendar example**](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/cal/index.html)

What I am looking to do is wipe out all the events and start fresh with my own event dates. There are many locations where I see date occurance,

- "[**events.json**](http://pastebin.com/vrwiRhNj)"
- "[**jquery.eventCalendar.js**](http://pastebin.com/MC9B8w3E)"
- "[**event.humanDate.json.php**](http://pastebin.com/t0qPZdVt)"

One of the event entry is the following from events.json:

```
{
    "date": "1337594400000",
    "type": "HERE I AM",
    "title": "Project A meeting",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set",
    "url": "http://www.event1.com/"
},
```

How is the date calculated with: 1337594400000?

I looked at the documentation but wasn't too clear. If someone good with json could give me some ideas or how should I go on about starting it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just make a date object with the number (milliseconds since the epoch). `Date(1337594400000)` yields a date object equivalent to `"Mon Apr 22 2013 14:50:44 GMT-0500 (CDT)"`  -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Definitely got a better understanding of time/date. How do I start fresh so I set the date and time and events?

Comment: What I am trying to understand is how does events.json interact with event.humanDate.json.php to display the events. I added a new date event in the second file but do not see it reflect on the calendar.
In events.json there is a entry: { "date": "1334656800000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Project C Brainstorming", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event7.com/" } and the 1334656800000 equals to Tue, 04 Aug 44263 16:00:00 GMT but there is no entry in the calendar for August.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the unix time with milliseconds.

Take your value `1337594400000`, then remove miliseconds `1337594400` and convert with this site for example : http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm => Mon, 21 May 2012 10:00:00 GMT

You can obtain the unix time with milliseconds using gettime() function of a JS date http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

or `echo (date('U')*1000)` in PHP for exemple.

Comment: Definitely got a better understanding of time/date. How do I start fresh so I set the date and time and events?